# JMXmon dynamic values handling

Tags: jmeter, jmx

i am trying to monitor weblogic coherence stats using mbeans. it has dynamic value. how can i get these dynamic values using some code instead of jconsole Mbean info retrieving. All i am trying is; run a script, get Mbean dynamic value, update Jmeter JMX script. Attaching  Mbean and JMeter JMXmon screenshots for the dynamic values reference

thanks
Chakravarthi[image: Coherence Mbean][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query an [MBean attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html) from any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Check out [Client.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/examples/Basic/Client.java) example code for reference, my expectation is that you should come up with something like:

```
import javax.management.ObjectName
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL

def url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://your_host:your_port/jmxrmi")
def connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null)
def connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection()
def object1 = new ObjectName("com.tangosol.coherence.component.manageable:type=Cache,service=DistributedCache....")
def value1 = connection.getAttribute(object1, "front").toString()

vars.put('value1', value1)
```

Once done you should be able to access the extracted attribute as `${value1}` where required.